# Timeout in React using old state data when triggered

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setstate

I am trying to create a simple notification provider for React, and it works wonderful if you click the notifications away. But a timeout function for the children, when using the "finished" function passed down from parent to child, seems to use an old state. Almost like the timeout snapshots the data, or the setState is being queued to after the timeout completes. Can the timeout be used, or do I need to rethink the auto disappearing?

```js
import styles from "@styles/Notification.module.scss";
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import NotificationCard from "@components/Notifications/Notification";
import { uuid4 } from "@sentry/utils";

export interface NotificationInterface {
  notifications: Notification[];
  info(notification: Notification): void;
  success(notification: Notification): void;
  warning(notification: Notification): void;
  error(notification: Notification): void;
}

export interface Notification {
  id?: string;
  message: string;
  level?: NotificationLevel;
  timeout?: number;
  delay?: number;
}

export enum NotificationLevel {
  INFO = "info",
  SUCCESS = "success",
  WARNING = "warning",
  ERROR = "error"
}

export const NotificationContext = createContext<NotificationInterface>({} as NotificationInterface);

export const NotificationProvider = ({ children }: { children?: JSX.Element }) => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState<Notification[]>([]);

  const createNotification = (notification: Notification): Notification => {
    return {
      id: uuid4(),
      level: notification.level || NotificationLevel.INFO,
      message: notification.message || "",
      timeout: notification.timeout || 5000,
      delay: notification.delay || 0
    };
  };

  const info = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.INFO })]);
  };

  const success = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.SUCCESS })]);
  };

  const warning = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.WARNING })]);
  };

  const error = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.ERROR })]);
  };

  const finished = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications(notifications.filter((n) => n.id !== notification.id));
  };

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider
      value={{
        notifications,
        info,
        success,
        warning,
        error
      }}
    >
      <div className={styles.notificationContainer}>
        {notifications.map((notification) => (
          <NotificationCard key={notification.id} notification={notification} onFinished={(n) => finished(n)} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {children}
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
import styles from "@styles/Notification.module.scss";
import { Notification } from "@utils/notificationProvider";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const NotificationCard = ({
  notification,
  onFinished
}: {
  notification: Notification;
  onFinished?: (notification: Notification) => void;
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  const close = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (onFinished) {
        onFinished(notification);
      }
    }, 500);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      close();
    }, notification.timeout);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => close()} className={isOpen ? styles.notificationCard : styles.notificationCardClosed}>
      {notification.message}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotificationCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with async code, (but i recommend to use it nearly always). When using old state when setting your state, use callback instead of value.
Because value from state will be change after rerender, but in callback prop, i is changed imidieatally.

Example:

instead of this

```
const info = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.INFO })]);
  };
```

use this

```
const info = (notification: Notification) => {
    setNotifications((oldNotifications)=>[...oldNotifications, createNotification({ ...notification, level: NotificationLevel.INFO })]);
  };
```

this way, you are always working with current data

Comment: Thank you, this worked, specifically on the finished method.